# contact form not sending data

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm using a the following to have a contact page send me a email with visitors data.

```
            <form method="post" action="submit.php">
            <label for="Name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />

            <label for="Email">eMail</label>
            <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />



            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="submit-button" />
            </form>
```

and the php:

```
    <?php

    $EmailFrom = "Me";
    $EmailTo = "me@me.com";
    $Subject = "Test";
    $Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
    $Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 

    // validation
    $validationOK=true;
    if (!$validationOK) {
      print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
      exit;
    }

    // prepare email body text
    $Body = "";
    $Body .= "Name: ";
    $Body .= $Name;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "eMail: ";
    $Body .= $Email;
    $Body .= "\n";

    // send email 
    $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: $EmailFrom");

    // redirect to success page 
    if ($success){
      print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=ok.html\">";
    }
    else{
      print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
    }
    ?>
```

When trying it out I only get the email body text prepared by the PHP file but none of the information inserted by the visitor, like this:

Name:
eMail:

Comment: Are you sure you have a mail server installed on your machine ?

Comment: I have uploaded this to the clients server but no result.

Comment: try trim instead of Trim (best practice). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643496/are-php-functions-case-sensitive

Comment: 1. Check the contents of `$_POST` upon submission (`var_dump($_POST);`). 2. Is the URL rewritten (by mod_rewrite) or redirected by `ErrorDocument` or `Redirect` by chance?

Comment: Try to echo your `$Body` and is it showing the correct data?

Comment: sorry, how do I echo the $Body?

Comment: add `echo $Body;` one line before `//send email`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set header information for E-Mail:

```
$header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
$header .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";
$header .= 'From: '.$EmailFrom."\r\n";

$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $header);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just simplified it a little bit.. also it seemed to be a "case sensitive" issue that stopped the form to communicate with the php file.

So this is what worked in the end:

```
            <form method="post" action="submit.php">
            <label for="Name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="Name" id="name" />

            <label for="Email">eMail</label>
            <input type="text" name="Email" id="email" />

            <label for="Message">Message</label>
            <textarea name="Message" rows="10" id="message"></textarea>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="submit" id="submit"/>
            </form>
```

and the php:

```
        <?php


    $EmailFrom = "Test";
    $EmailTo = "test@test.com";
    $Subject = "Testing";
    $Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
    $Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
    $Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 

    // validation
    $validationOK=true;
    if (!$validationOK) {
      print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
      exit;
    }

    // prepare email body text
    $Body = "";
    $Body .= "Name: ";
    $Body .= $Name;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "eMail: ";
    $Body .= $Email;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Message: ";
    $Body .= $Message;
    $Body .= "\n";

    // send email 
    $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: $EmailFrom");

    // redirect to success page 
    if ($success){
      print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=ok.htm\">";
    }
    else{
      print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
    }
    ?>
```