# Redirect to previous page after destroying session

Tags: php, javascript, session, redirect, destroy

I am working with php sessions and user accounts.  When they click on the Log Out link on a page it generates the code in logout.php which is...

```
<? 
session_start();
session_destroy();
Header( “Location: http://www.espn.com” );
?>
```

The page destroys the session and for some reason it just goes back to the index.php page.  I want to have it so that when the user is log out they are redirected to the page THEY WERE JUST ON logged out.  I think I need to just change the code in my logout.php but I don't know what to do.  I tried testing it by taking the user to espn.com but this didn't even work.  Can someone help me set it up so that the user is sent to the page they were just on.
Live Long and Prosper.

Comment: this seems legit. should work. show me more of the php as well as the html where this is invoked.

Comment: Pablo functions are case-insentitive in php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643496/are-php-functions-case-sensitive

Comment: This isn't what I want.  It is just an example.  I want to redirect to the previous page the user was on not espn.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Header( “Location: http://www.espn.com” );
```

Should be

```
header("Location: http://www.espn.com"); //<--NOTE: You are using wrong quotes!
```

***PS:*** Although php functions are case insensitive, but you'd better use the low case `head` same with manual.

***Update:***
If you want to  redirect to the previous page, you could do:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
} else {
    header("Location: http://www.espn.com");
}
exit;
```

Comment: OK thank you, but I want to redirect to the previous page the user was on.  That was just an example.

Comment: do i put this before or after the start and destroy session?

Comment: it didn't work. it just takes me to index.php.  THis is the  code for my logout.php...

Comment: if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
} else {
    header("Location: http://www.espn.com");
}
exit;

Comment: Do an `echo` on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` then. What is returned?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the previous page using:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

So if you set the your header location to that address, it should send the user back to the previous page

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Although be warned that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` may be empty, you should check for this first and if it is empty send them elsewhere, like your homepage.