# How to parse JSON string in php

Tags: php, json

I'm getting below JSON response:

```
[{"startDate":"2012-07-12 11:21:38 +0530","totalTime":0},{"startDate":"2012-07-11 11:27:33 +0530","totalTime":0},{"startDate":"2012-07-16 18:38:37 +0530","totalTime":0},{"startDate":"2012-07-17 14:18:32 +0530","totalTime":0}]
```

i want make array of start date and totalTime, i have used these two lines but it wont work $obj, please suggest..

```
                    $obj  = json_decode($dateTimeArr); 
        $dateAr = $obj->{'startDate'};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As everyone said, and you did - use `json_decode`.

```
    $dateArrays  = json_decode($dateTimeArr, true); // decode JSON to associative array
    foreach($dateArrays as $dateArr){
        echo $dateArr['startDate']; 
        echo $dateArr['totalTime']; 
    }
```

In future, if you are unsure what type or structure of data is in the variable, do `var_dump($var)` and it will print type of variable and its content.

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy:

```
$Arr = json_decode($JSON, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) will give you nested PHP types you can then descend to retrieve your data.

Comment: i want make array of start date, i have used these two lines but it wont work $obj, please suggest..   $obj  = json_decode($dateTimeArr); 
   $dateAr = $obj->{'startDate'};

Answer (score 1):

use **json_decode($json_response,true)** to convert json to Array

Answer (score 0):

Guess what you are looking for is `json_decode()`

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php for the inner workings

Comment: i want make array of start date, i have used these two lines but it wont work $obj, please suggest..   $obj  = json_decode($dateTimeArr); 
   $dateAr = $obj->{'startDate'};

Comment: @rekire It isn't actually in this case but I agree that's ugly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643496/are-php-functions-case-sensitive

Comment: Try this: `$obj = json_decode($dateTimeArr); $dateAr = $obj->startDate;` You're mixing up object and array notation there