# PHP is case sensitive then why print_R is working?

Tags: php

PHP is case sensitive that is mentioned in the PHP manual. For display `array` we use `print_r()` which is an built-in `array` function of PHP then why `print_R()` is working ?

Comment: A quick search on SO or Google could have answered this for you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5643544/138383

Comment: It's not case sensitive, [Codepad](http://codepad.org/K4001zDI)

Comment: Functions and methods names are not case-sensitive.

But variables names are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

See below url:-

[Are PHP functions case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643496/are-php-functions-case-sensitive)

http://www.wellho.net/mouth/93_Case-Sensitive-.html

**Read it**

I am quoting from [this](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php):

Note: Function names are case-insensitive, though it is usually good form to call functions as they appear in their declaration.

So, its looks like user-defined is case-sensitive, there were a vote for making functions/objects under PHP5 case-sensitive.