# Trying to make a class called "List", but the list() function is breaking it

Tags: php, function, class, case-sensitive

```
class List {
  public function hello()
  {
    return "hello";
  }
}

$list = new List;

echo $list::hello();
```

**Gives Error:**

```
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'List' (T_LIST), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in /home/WtGTRQ/prog.php on line 3
```

Changing "List" to "Lizt" fixes the issue.

I sadly understand that [Php functions are case-insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643496/are-php-functions-case-sensitive), but I really don't want to make a List object a Lizt object... Is there some way to circumvent this without renaming my class?

Comment: How about `MyList` or something with a little more context on what the list is ?

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: also no.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`List` is a restricted PHP word.

`You cannot use any of the following words as constants, class names, function or method names.`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

--

To answer your question, you will have to change your `list` class name to something else. `MyList`, `CarList`, `Listing`, etc..

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. `list` looks to be the reserved word, not `List`.

Comment: @Josh H it makes sense: `Note: Function names are case-insensitive, though it is usually good form to call functions as they appear in their declaration.` from here: http://fr.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php