# Expecting identifier T_STRING

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel seems to be throwing an error at line 3 `use App\List;` but I can't seem to figure out the problem as I'm new to Laravel (perhaps it's a PHP version issue?).

Error:
`syntax error, unexpected 'List' (T_LIST), expecting identifier (T_STRING)`

Here is my `PageController` Class:

```
<?php

use App\List;
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function home(){
      $lists = List::all();
      return view('home', compact('lists'));
    }
}
```

and here is `App\List`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class List extends Model
{
    public function items(){
      return $this->hasMany(ListItem::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: down-voting without giving any reason? it's ridiculous.

Comment: List is a reserved keyword. try naming something else

Comment: Facepalm. Thank you.

Comment: `it's ridiculous` no, its called lack of research, did u even try to put your error message on google? The very first result for me was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794279/trying-to-make-a-class-called-list-but-the-list-function-is-breaking-it

Answer (score 4):

You cannot name a class `List`. See more: [List of Reserved Words](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.php)

Comment: I was trying for hours to find the solution. it does work .thanks

Comment: The reserved word is `list`, and not `List`. I would consider this a language bug.

Comment: Came across this issue. That's pretty crappy. 'Public' and 'List' are perfectly usable words in modeling business logic. Why on earth does PHP care if they're used in the class namespace!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot name a class `List`. I have had this issue, it is a [reserved word](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php).

Comment: Facepalm. Thank you.

Comment: No worries, only reason I know is I recently did the same thing!