# What is imagepng and ImagePng?

Tags: php, image, gd

I am using a library that used `ImagePng()` to generate png files. However I got `Fatal error: Call to undefined function ImagePng()`. I have enabled `GD` extension according to `phpinfo`.

I can run the script with CLI, but cannot with a webserver(apache).

Is `ImagePng` the same one as `imagepng`?

The two phps are different, the one run in CLI is 5.5.23, and the one run in web server is 5.5.20 (built in with Yosemite).

### I just found that php function names are NOT case sensitive! WTF!

Can you tell me what extension should I enable to use `imagepng`? I have already enabled `GD2`.

## update

`imagepng` and `ImagePng` are the same because php's function/class names are case-insensitive.

The problem here is that the built in PHP's GD extension of MacOS X doesn't support PNG and FreeType. Problem solved according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493762/yosemite-php-gd-mcrypt-installation).

Comment: nope imagepng() is diff from ImagePng() .  check this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php

Comment: @Satya They are the same, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643496/are-php-functions-case-sensitive/5643544#5643544