# Form sending blank values

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I'm making a simple form using HTML, CSS and PHP.

Currently the form sends an email to the identified recipient but does not contain any information from the form, just the headers identified in the $formcontent.

**HTML**

```
<form method ="post" action="index.php">      
    <input name="name" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Name" />   
    <input name="email" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Email" />
    <textarea name="message" class="feedback-input" placeholder="message"></textarea>
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
form { max-width:455px; margin-right:45px; margin-top:10px; float: right; display: inline; }

.feedback-input {
  color:white;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight:500;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  line-height: 22px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border:2px solid #CC6666;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  padding: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width:100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline:0;
}

.feedback-input:focus { border:2px solid #CC4949; }

textarea {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60%;
  resize:vertical;
}

[type="submit"] {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  background:#CC6666;
  border-radius:5px;
  border:0;
  cursor:pointer;
  color:white;
  font-size:24px;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  margin-top:-4px;
  font-weight:700;
}
[type="submit"]:hover { background:#CC4949; }
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$name = $_post['name'];
$email = $_post['email'];
$message = $_post['message'];
$formcontent = "From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = 'info@beardmore.cc';
$subject = 'Beardmore.cc contact form';
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";?>
```

Comment: Should be `$_POST` not `$_post`.

Comment: php variable names, functions, etc. are case sensitive as @Albzi pointed out.

Comment: Along with what @Albzi said make sure you check your values are set by doing `if(isset($_POST['name']))`.

Comment: @Julio, you’re only half right on that … function names are _not_ case sensitive … see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5643496/1427878, http://the-echoplex.net/log/php-case-sensitivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Albzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2471423/albzi) noted [in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152827/php-form-sending-blanks#comment54115080_33152827), In PHP the case is important, you need to edit your code to have `$_POST` instead of `$_post`:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent = "From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = 'info@beardmore.cc';
$subject = 'Beardmore.cc contact form';
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";?>
```

You should also sanitize your variables, in this state your code is unprotected against malicious users. Additionnaly, check if they are set with the [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function.

Comment: ok that's cool.  I din't know that.  The name now works but it doesn't send the message.  I've checked all my spelling.  What else am I missing.  Thanks for the help

Comment: I suggest you to make another question with this problem, and validate this answer if it helped you ;) For your second problem, try to test your `mail`function alone in another PHP file, to see if you're able to send email. Then, add the code missing. @stee1e