# What is the difference between Array and array?

Tags: php, arrays, type-declaration

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmhKXSCXn-k&list=PLzEjYXjNpfl7YfeAPHVeKE-BfQhraHmva&index=7) OOP tutorial, I noticed the following code:

```
public function validate(Array $data, Array $rules){}
```

My question is if that is the same as:

```
public function validate(array $data, array $rules){}
```

In the [PHP.net documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration), I could find a reference only to the second form.

Comment: It seems that they both mean the same thing. In other news; during a little research for this question I have found out that PHP is in general completely case-insensitive. Ergo: you can use whatever case you'd like.

Comment: What do you mean by "completely case-insensitive"? Are you talking about all php code or only reserved words?

Comment: I'm talking about quite a big part of PHP, as said in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18516698/5147246) in [this SA question: 'Are PHP functions case sensitive?'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643496/are-php-functions-case-sensitive). [This blogpost](http://the-echoplex.net/log/php-case-sensitivity) has done some research on this matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are both the same. Some IDEs only recognize one of the forms, though. (Just like stackoverflow itself, which only stylizes `Array`

Comment: Yes, even you can declare your array like this: `$arr = aRrAy(1, 2, 3);`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: PHP constructs, class names, functions and user-defined functions are case-insensitive.

Comment: Functions yes, variable names not: `$aaa = 'a'; echo $AAA;` -> undefixed $AAA

Comment: Thanks @Martijn for pointing that out, I've corrected.

Answer (score -5):

Javascript can only usw "Array". Using "array" in PHP is no problem, but if you want do use Javascript too, it will cause an error.

Comment: Javascript is an unrelated context.