# Why are PHP booleans both lower case and upper case?

Tags: language-design

Is there a difference between `true` and `TRUE` or `false` and `FALSE` in PHP?

Comment: Because you could have found this out yourself in five seconds with Google.

Comment: Then what's up with this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013848/uppercase-booleans-vs-lowercase-in-php if all there is to this can be googled in 5 mins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

> To specify a boolean literal, use the keywords TRUE or FALSE. Both are case-insensitive.

Answer (score 4):

If you intend to use JSON then the standard RFC7159 says :

> The literal names MUST be lowercase. No other literal names are allowed.

And from [Php 5.6](https://php.net/manual/en/migration56.incompatible.php) :

> json_decode() now rejects non-lowercase variants of the JSON literals true, false and null at all times, as per the JSON specification

And according to [PSR-2 standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) :

> PHP keywords MUST be in lower case.
>
> The PHP constants true, false, and null MUST be in lower case.

*Ps.: I could not post link to the RFC7159 because of SO limitations.*

Answer (score 2):

Constants are case-sensitive per default. But for symmetry to the other identifier namespaces, they can be defined case-insensitively:

```
 define("mixedCASE", 123, TRUE);

 print MiXeDcAsE;
```

And that's just how `TRUE` and `FALSE` were pre-declared. (They aren't parser/language builtins.)

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the PHP Parser isn't very fussy when it comes to TRUE, true and FALSE, false